# Detect whether a checkbox is checked or not in asp.net and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have a CheckBox control within a asp:Panel like below:

```
<asp:Panel ID="chk" runat="server" Visible="false" CssClass="checkbox checkbox-primary checkbox-single">
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="valCheck" />
</asp:Panel>
```

I need to be able to check to see if this CheckBox is being checked or not then I would send 0 or 1 to a function that will do some more stuff and when comes back based on the value, if it's more than 0 it will display a checked check box. I need to use this value, because I also have some other types of inputs as well which I set their value based on the value coming back from another call.

```
var checking = false;
function saveCheckBoxData(obj, id, inputType) {
    if (checking) return;
    checking = true;
    var date = $("#MainContent_date").val();
    var column = $(obj).attr("column");
    var dataFieldId = $(obj).attr("dataFieldId ");
    var shift = $(obj).attr("shift");
    var val = 0;
    //if ($("#valCheck").is(':checked')) {
    //    val = 1;
    //}
    //if ($('#valCheck').prop('checked')) {
    //    val = 1;
    //}
    //if ($('#valCheck').attr("checked")) {
    //    val = 1;
    //}
    SaveInput(dataFieldId , shift, inputType, date, column, id, val);
}
```

When I call SaveInput function, I need to either pass 0 (if checkbox is not checked) or 1 (when it's checked). The lines I've commented out did not work!

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check in browser that you have got same `#valCheck` as `id` to your `checkbox`

Comment: try `$('<%=valCheck.ClientID %>').is(':checked')` if you have written the js code in same aspx page.

Comment: I think asp.net change the id while sending the page to browser, so use `ClientIDMode="static"` in your checkbox field and then try.

Comment: @Prashant Shirke  my js code is in a different file!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The id is not exactly `valCheck` when you use `runat="server"`the element id changes(inspect the element to see the new id), then you need to use the jquery selector like:

```
$("select[id*='valCheck']")
```

or

```
$("select[id$='valCheck']")
```

or you can simply add the attr `ClientIdMode="Static"` in your asp element.

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="valCheck" ClientIdMode="Static" />
```

If you want to understand why it happens, take a look at that [article](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/703_Understanding_ClientIDMode_Mode_Feature_in_ASP_net_4_0.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The ClientIdMode="Static" would not work in my case, it will destroy the look and feel of my check boxes!
I have more than one check box in every page, so I need to constantly check the status of check boxes.
The $("select[id*='valCheck']") will help me to see if this input is a check box, now I need to check the checked/unchecked for each check box. Does this require a loop?

Comment: @zezz You are welcome, most of the time I use the jquery selector as well.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my first comment, I thought I'd send you a notification in case you missed that!

Comment: @zezz You can use `.each` of jquery, going through all the checkboxes: `$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () { if (this.checked){...}});`

Comment: var val;
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            val = 1;
        }
        else
            val = 0;
    })
It always return true (val = 1), even when I unchecked the check box!!

Comment: I guess I need some kind of event handler or binding, if I'm correct?

Comment: @zezz Take a look in this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mathiasfcx/5p147w6p/), I believe this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

In plain javascript

```
 var isChecked= document.getElementById("myCheck").checked;
```

`isChecked` will be  `true` if checked and `false` if not checked